# Big Sur 11.3 beta removes command line tools (CLT) and reinstalls same version present on 11.2

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, software-update, beta

Prior to 11.3 beta install:

```
Xcode: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815 
CommandLineTools: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
```

Post 11.3 beta

```
Xcode: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
CommandLineTools: not installed <---------------
```

I started a script (that does some git stuff) and was prompted to install the CLT.

I was stumped (I knew I had CLT installed), but I went ahead and allowed the reinstallation of CLT.

Afterwards, this is shown:

```
Xcode: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
CommandLineTools: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
```

So it appears that the beta uninstalled CLT and then reinstalled the exact same version of CLT I had prior to the beta release installation.

Anyone else see this behavior?

Comment: <shrug> Well known, not news.  Homebrew has been whining about this for ages.

Comment: It is a beta so this is expected behaviour. Report it as a bug. This I s why betas are released. So that users find bugs b

Comment: I reported it via feedback assistant.  Looks like it's been happening for some time as Marc pointed out.